# convert existing record to new record automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am wondering if, in some hidden corner of the API I haven't yet run into, if there is a way to clone an existing record into a new one, so when saved it will have a new id assigned?

This is intended to be used on an event site I am writing, which will allow people to import from previous years, but copying it will allow updating the event description with new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dup`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup) method for this.

Given object `user1` of model `User`, you can do:

```
user2 = user1.dup
user2.save
```

Doing `user2 = user1.dup` clones `user1` into `user2`, and `user2` has no `id`, `created_at` and `updated_at` values assigned and it is treated as a new record.

Comment: Thanks!  I had hoped it would be so simple.  For some reason, I swore this did not work when I tried it.